# web3js signing the message using private key

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I tried using `web3.eth.accounts.sign('hello', 'PrivateKey')` to sign my message and used `web3.eth.accounts.recover(signatureObject)` to recover the address 
but it does not return me the correct address. I am using web3 version : 1.0.0-beta.34. Any help ?

Comment: It's working for me. Could you share full, runnable code?

Comment: A quick test that worked for me: `web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.eth.accounts.sign('hello', '0xc59d0e9549ee7b7e8da37cedffd195c2cd09d8a0e56af4c75e36088c80028834')) == '0x6056b0757Ef1fdb34b59bBB666f41d52aa782f38'`

Comment: Note that I was on 1.0.0-beta.35, just in case there really was a bug in this.

Comment: I tried this  `web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.eth.accounts.sign('hello', web3.utils.toHex('832A51879E99EF04F2407E9E4C3DFC78FB032B0BB57DAEB2DEE8956E8908A91E'))) == '0x476637335902321375b004df6a35df225edbb8c0'`  and it returns false. Is it because I am converting to hex ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you already have hex, so calling `toHex` on it doesn't make sense. Just put a `0x` in front of it. `web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.eth.accounts.sign('hello', '0x832A51879E99EF04F2407E9E4C3DFC78FB032B0BB57DAEB2DEE8956E8908A91E')).toLowerCase() == '0x476637335902321375b004df6a35df225edbb8c0'`

Comment: Nope . My private key is not in Hex, so I converted to hex and then sign. However this also does not work `web3.eth.accounts.recover(web3.eth.accounts.sign('hello', '0xB9B7B3DFF56A5D6DFE7F8DBBE038B495F257ABCCF67DC7ABB661FE6D5DBB7057')) == '0x8fb5cd5d55591c1bba97879eee0367d78446342c'`.

Comment: You missed the `.toLowerCase()` in my previous comment. (I see you're now using a different private key, but adding `toLowerCase()` still works for that one.)

Comment: Yep . I was missing that toLowerCase. Thanks much !

Comment: Ping me on my profile, I have solution